# Nginx in LXD container: remote_addr showing host IP instead of client IP in logs

Tags: lxd

I used the command `lxc config device add nginx-proxy hostport443 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:443 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:443` to allow the nginx service within the "nginx-proxy" instance to respond to client requests on port 443 of the host device. However, I noticed in the nginx logs that the `remote_addr` is now showing the IP address of the host device instead of the actual client IP address. What should I do to resolve this issue?